# org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, multipartform-data

How to handle

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException:
>   The field fileName exceeds its maximum permitted size of 3145728
>   bytes.

This happens after uploading a file which is bigger than maxFileSize limit in servlet @MultipartConfig. Is there a way to load in browser custom error page or something else because after that client recievs

> The connection was reset

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the normal servlet error-page mechanism should catch this, so add this to `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/internalerror.html</location>
</error-page>
```

or to catch any error code, just leave out the `<error-code>` tag:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/anyerror.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: it's present & has no effect

Comment: can you post the whole stack? could it be that the exception is caught somewhere, like in one of your filters? It should propagate high enough so that the servlet container can 'see' it.